# Quota sampling participants

Tags: sampling

We need to select participants, based on the quotas provided. For example:

exactly 15 men
exactly 15 women

exactly 10 young
exactly 10 middle aged
exactly 10 old

exactly 10 poor
exactly 10 middle class
exactly 10 rich

The total number of participants should be exactly 30.

### What algorithm should be used to do that?

Simpler, more detailed, example.
Let's say that output quota is: 4 people: 2 women, 2 men, 2 old, 2 young.

Input set is:

```
Man Young
Man Young
Man Old
Woman Old
Woman Young
```

So the matching output set should be:

```
Man Young
Man Old
Woman Young
Woman Old
```

If we'll just start adding people to the output set one by one, skipping those, that would go over the quota, we'll end up with:

Man Young
Man Young
Woman Old

We'll have Man Old and Woman Young left, but none of those would match the quota.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. Which is the intended input and output of your algorithm?

Comment: Input is the array of people. Each human has gender and age. The output should be array of people, arranged by the quota provided in the question.

Comment: Added a more detailed example.

Comment: This sounds like a constraint satisfaction problem (CSP). Take a look on that.

Comment: @JnxF Ah-ha! Thank you. Checking.